# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints in docker

Tags: linux, docker, dependencies, dockerfile, miniconda

I am new to docker.

**I have two questions**
**Question # 1**
I've created this basic docker file that installs the **Apache-Airflow** and **Apache-Celery**. But for now, just wanted to install airflow. I am facing a strange issue saying `unsatisfiable constraints`.

[image: error]

I'm getting tired. I've tried but not able to resolve the issue. Any help will be appreciated a lot.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /airflow

RUN apk add git gcc python3-dev gpgme-dev libc-dev python-devel python-setuptools mysql-devel gcc-c++

COPY airflow/requirements.txt airflow/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r airflow/requirements.txt
COPY . /airflow

EXPOSE 8080 5555

CMD ["airflow", "initdb"]
```

I've my requirements.txt file which has the dependencies for Apache-Airflow.

requirements.txt

```
pytz==2015.7
cryptography
requests
pyOpenSSL
ndg-httpsclient
pyasn1
psycopg2
celery>=4.0.0
flower>=0.7.3

Flask==1.1.1
requests==2.22.0
airflow==1.10.8
MySQL-python
flask_bcrypt
```

**Question # 2**

We use `conda-library` image `continuumio/miniconda3` to install the dependencies. Is it a good approach to use???

Comment: And what if we create dockerfile using `continuumio/miniconda3` image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few changes, here's the new dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /airflow

RUN apk add build-base libffi-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev mariadb-connector-c-dev

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /airflow

EXPOSE 8080 5555

CMD ["airflow", "initdb"]
```

And the new requirements.txt:

```
pytz==2015.7
cryptography
pyOpenSSL
ndg-httpsclient
pyasn1
psycopg2
celery>=4.0.0
flower>=0.7.3

Flask==1.1.1
requests==2.22.0
apache-airflow==1.10.8
mysqlclient
flask_bcrypt
```

Summary of changes:

- You were trying to download packages that don't exist in Alpine (they look like debian packages), I replaced most of them with `apk add build-base`
- added `libffi-dev` for the `cryptography` package
- added `musl-dev` and `postgresql-dev` for psycopg2
- MySQL-python doesn't support python3 so I replaced it with `mysqlclient`
- added `mariadb-connect-c-dev` for `mysqlclient`
- other minor fixes, fixed copy paths, removed duplicate dependencies

And yes, generally you might be better off not using alpine to build python packages (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/) . If you switch to `continuumio/miniconda3` it is a little simpler (and much faster to build).

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /airflow

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev libmariadbclient-dev build-essential

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /airflow

EXPOSE 8080 5555

CMD ["airflow", "initdb"]
```